# C# Compilation to be done from a EDITOR with JSON Support (Serialize and Deserialize)

Tags: c#, roslyn, system.reflection

I am here after spending weeks trying to resolve the below issue.

I have c# code which is written in the front end editor.
We use Monaco Editor on the front end to write the code.
That code is compiled and saved as assembly in our Blob Store.

Right now, i am stuck with the below error
[image]
[image]

As per the pic, i get a Json string input as ratings.
When i try deserialize into a object which is inside the class ( in the editor ), it throws exceptions.

I use CSharpCompilation to compile the code at run time and execute the method "Execute" in the editor.

The code in the editor goes into the below

```
            try
            {
                CSharpCompilation compilation = CreateCompilation(code); // c# code from editor
                byte[] bytes = ConvertToArray(compilation);
                assembly = Assembly.Load(bytes);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception($"{CODE_INVALID_MESSAGE}: '{ex.Message}'");
            }


//CreateCompilation Method
```

private static CSharpCompilation CreateCompilation(string code)
{
SyntaxTree syntaxTree = SyntaxFactory.ParseSyntaxTree(code);
var runtimeAssemblyDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(object).Assembly.Location);

```
        MetadataReference stringReference = AssemblyMetadata
          .CreateFromFile(typeof(string).Assembly.Location)
          .GetReference();

        MetadataReference enumerableReference = AssemblyMetadata
          .CreateFromFile(typeof(Enumerable).Assembly.Location)
          .GetReference();

        MetadataReference systemReference = AssemblyMetadata
          .CreateFromFile(Path.Combine(runtimeAssemblyDirectory, "System.dll"))
          .GetReference();

        MetadataReference runtimeReference = AssemblyMetadata
          .CreateFromFile(Path.Combine(runtimeAssemblyDirectory, "System.Runtime.dll"))
          .GetReference();

        MetadataReference systemCoreReference = AssemblyMetadata
          .CreateFromFile(Path.Combine(runtimeAssemblyDirectory, "System.Core.dll"))
          .GetReference();

        MetadataReference jsonReference = AssemblyMetadata
          .CreateFromFile(Path.Combine(runtimeAssemblyDirectory, "System.Text.Json.dll"))
          .GetReference();

        //MetadataReference jsonSerialisationReference = AssemblyMetadata
        //  .CreateFromFile(Path.Combine(runtimeAssemblyDirectory, "System.Text.Json.Serialization.dll"))
        //  .GetReference();

        CSharpCompilation compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create
        (
            assemblyName: Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            syntaxTrees: new[] { syntaxTree },
            options: new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary),
            references: new[] { stringReference, enumerableReference, systemReference, runtimeReference, systemCoreReference, jsonReference }
        );

        return compilation;
    }

 So, when i run this, i am getting JSON Value could not converted. Please can someone help me in the right direction
```

Tx
Shankar

Comment: Error message says that it failed to convert your JSON convert to your viewModel. Can you provide your json and viewModel?

Comment: Have you tried running the actual code you want to use without the runtime compilation boilerplate by simply compiling it and then run/debug it? Does that work?

Comment: Like mentioned, if i pasted that piece of code n LinqPad etc, it will work. The problem is that code on the editor gets compiled and the method "Execute" is called and before i call CSharpCompilation, i include System.Net.Json, but still it does not recognize